# MikTeX repository connection issues

Tags: miktex2.9

As it seems, I am having issues with my Miktex (2.9) distribution, as I am not able to download necessary packages, neither on the fly nor via the package manager. The following error message keeps poping up:

[image]

When checking the repository status (miktex.org/pkg/repositories), the relevant host is shown as online. It seems not to be particularly linked to any Wifi issues as it does not work on a number of Wifi connections. 
When trying to install on the fly via TexMaker/R Sweave, the following error keeps coming back

[image]

I can not simply change the repository as the first error message will be shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: your issue is reminiscent of firewall / proxy problems are you in a corporate/educational setup or have managed internet access  ?

Comment: Is your issue solved? How?